# Can't figure out how to use Mechanize with Python to select items from a dropdown box on an ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, python, html, mechanize

I have an ASP.NET page (located here: http://www.kraftrecipes.com/Products/ProductMain.aspx) that has a dropdown box of various food brands. I'm trying to use Mechanize in Python so I can click on each item in the list, go to the product list page, and eventually use BeautifulSoup to scrape product information. Here's some of the HTML:

```
<fieldset  class="pulldownfieldset">

    <label>...or use the pulldown menu below.</label>

    <select name="ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_9bdf5859_9c73_4144_8b6a_9a3b3df417d5$ctl01$ddlBrand"
            id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_9bdf5859_9c73_4144_8b6a_9a3b3df417d5_ctl01_ddlBrand"
            onkeypress="return doSubmit(event, 'ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_9bdf5859_9c73_4144_8b6a_9a3b3df417d5_ctl01_btnBrandGo');">

    <option value="322">Arrowroot</option>

    <option value="1">A.1. Steak Sauces and Marinades</option>
    etc.
```

At first I just tried selecting the form, but Python complained that it didn't exist.

```
browser.select_form("ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_9bdf5859_9c73_4144_8b6a_9a3b3df417d5$ctl01$ddlBrand")
```

When I do this:

```
browser.select_form(nr=0)
print browser.form
```

I get a list of all of the forms, but doing `browser.form.name` yields "aspnetForm", which leads me to believe that Mechanize sees everything on the page as one big form. If this is true, how can I get at the selections in the dropdown box and submit them?

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one form on the page. What you want is controls.
Try:

```
form = browser.forms()[0]
control = form.find_control(name="ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_9bdf5859_9c73_4144_8b6a_9a3b3df417d5$ctl01$ddlBrand")
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked with a small modification:
`browser.select_form(nr=0)
control = browser.find_control(name="ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_9bdf5859_9c73_4144_8b6a_9a3b3df417d5$ctl01$ddlBrand")`